# Height of divs - should be equal and flexible

Tags: css

I would like to have three columns:

- *left column* (red background)
- *center column* (yellow background)
- *right column* (black background)

HTML, like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left_column">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="center_column">
        <p>loooooong text</p>
        <p>other text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right_column">
    </div>
</div>​
```

**Every column should have the same height (flexible)**

I made demo http://jsfiddle.net/4hj4f/8/ - but this CSS is wrong - columns have different height

Answer (score 1):

You can use **display:table** for this type of functionality. Write like this:

```
body, html{height:100%}
#container {
    height: 100%;   
   display:table;    
}

#left_column, #center_column, #right_column {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/4hj4f/9/

Comment: you may check out [this](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/) article to get more info about `display: table` property.

Answer (score 0):

Set container height. Its enough for set your condition.

```
#container {
height: 500px;            
}
```

Demo : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hj4f/12/)